# CreateJS getObjectsUnderPoint when alpha = 0

Tags: javascript, alpha, easeljs, createjs

I need to get all bitmaps under point in a container. The bitmaps alpha is set to 0 and this doesnt seem to work with this method.

Are there any alternatives? I cant just add an event listener to the object as that is not enough in this scenario.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If you just want to get the objects under a point you'd have to loop through all children of the container and call `hitTest(x,y)` (http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/DisplayObject.html#method_hitTest) this ignores the alpha-value. (remember to call the method with the coordinates in the object's local coordinate space)

2) If you want to work with EventListeners and Alpha-0 objects, you can define another DisplayObject as the `hitArea` (http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/DisplayObject.html#property_hitArea) - in that case only the shape, alpha, ect.. of the hitArea object is used.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I am using hitTest but it doesn't seem to work as expected. I have a Square container with a 50x50 square within it at x=50 and y=50. When I click it and do the hit test it returns false, but when I click x=0 y=0 the hit test returns true

Comment: the hit test is being ran on the containers children

Comment: as I mentioned, you will have to translate the coordinates to each of the childrens local coordinate space, in your case that depends on where the listener is from: `localCoords = listenerObject.localToLocal(x,y,targetChild);` - that should do it

Comment: I have used hit test and it worked fine on a solid block, but when I use a triangle for instance, only the opaque parts are registered with hitTest, not the fully transparent parts.

Comment: Yes that is correct, but it ignores the alpha value of the display-object