# easeljs: getObjectsUnderPoint does not return all shapes

Tags: easeljs, createjs

I draw 2 shapes, one above the other. The getObjectsUnderPoint function returns only one shape even the point is part of both shapes. The point I get in addEventListener handler of the upper shape. Here is full [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5Rxm2/1/).

```js
var stage;

function init() {
    stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
    var rect = new createjs.Shape();
    rect.graphics.beginFill("#ff0000").drawRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
    stage.addChild(rect);
    var circle = new createjs.Shape();
    circle.graphics.beginFill("#00ff00").drawCircle(60, 60, 40);
    circle.addEventListener("click", onClick);
    stage.addChild(circle);
    stage.update();
}

function onClick(e) {
    // the length should be 2: circle + rectangle, but is only 1 ???
    alert(stage.getObjectsUnderPoint(e.stageX, e.stageY).length);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in 0.7.1 that has since been patched and is confirmed to be fixed in version 0.8.2 as Pim Schaaf has demonstrated with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/84oz06t4/). If you are stuck with version 0.7.1, you can use the workaround described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272286/createjs-getobjectsunderpoint-when-alpha-0) by iterating over the children of the container and calling `hitTest(x, y)` giving the mouseX and mouseY as parameters.

Comment: The link has died. It appears this is fixed in more recent versions of easeljs (0.8.2). See http://jsfiddle.net/84oz06t4 with EaselJS 0.8.2.

Comment: @PimSchaaf: I edited my answer to better explain the issue. Thanks for bringing the broken link to my attention.

Comment: Great, thanks! (small typo in my name there, but no worries xD)